# Migrating on-premises file shares to Azure

Tags: onedrive, migration, azure

I'm looking at migrating our on-premises file shares to One Drive for Business. I know I can use One Drive for Business for this but from what I've read the migration seems painful and they're not suited to departmental shares. I have several TBs of data, thousands of shares and hundreds of users.

What's the recommended approach for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AZURE File Storage would likely be a better candidate.

It works pretty much the same as if you were sharing on network locally via SMB but can enable you to remotely store the files in the cloud. You can also allocate permissions etc per department and later on can use the inbuilt REST API attached to each share to generate helper apps if need be.